# Filter Function Not Lazy

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

I'm making my very own version of Java's Stream library for fun. Here's my class signature:

```
class Stream<T> {
  Supplier<T> head;
  Supplier<Stream<T>> tail;
  ...
}
```

Also, I wrote a basic infinite stream iterator that would generate an infinite list based on the given function:

```
  public static <T> Stream<T> iterate(T first, Function<T, T> f) {
    return new Stream<T>(
            () -> first,
            () -> {
              T nextElem = f.apply(first);
              if (nextElem == null) {
                return generate(() -> null);
              } else {
                return iterate(nextElem, f);
              }
            }
    );
  }
```

The function `generate` is a special case of iterate that repeats a given element forever. In the function above, I'm generating an infinite sequence of `null` to indicate the end of the stream (I don't think I'll be storing null values in the stream).

I then wrote a reduce function where the reducing function is lazy on its second argument:

```
  public <U> U reduce(U acc, Function<T, Function<Supplier<U>, U>> f) {
    System.out.println("REDUCE CALL");
    T elem = head.get();
    if (elem != null) {
      return f.apply(elem).apply(() -> this.tail.get().reduce(acc, f));
    } else {
      return acc;
    }
  }
```

Building upon the reduce function, I wrote the filter function.

```
  public Stream<T> filter(Predicate<T> p) {
    System.out.println("FILTER");
    return reduce(generate(() -> null), elem -> acc -> {
      if (p.test(elem)) {
        return new Stream<>(
                () -> elem,
                () -> acc.get()
        );
      } else {
        return acc.get();
      }
    });
  }
```

Finally, I proceeded to use my very own Stream class:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream<Integer> ilist =
            Stream
              .iterate(1, x -> x + 1)
              .filter(x -> x >= 5);
  }
```

But filter isn't lazy! From the output given below, I think filter evaluates the elements until it finds one that matches the given predicate.

```
FILTER
REDUCE CALL
REDUCE CALL
REDUCE CALL
REDUCE CALL
REDUCE CALL
```

What's wrong with my code, and how can I make my filter function lazy again?

**Update**: Based on Sweeper's remarks, I had another go at the filter function without using reduce.

```
  public Stream<T> filter2(Predicate<T> p) {
    System.out.println("FILTER2");
    T elem = head.get();
    if (elem == null) {
      return generate(() -> null);
    } else {
      if (p.test(elem)) {
        return new Stream<>(
                () -> elem,
                () -> this.tail.get().filter2(p)
        );
      } else {
        return this.tail.get().filter2(p);
      }
    }
  }
```

However, this function isn't lazy as well. The output of my main function using `filter2` is as follows:

```
FILTER2
FILTER2
FILTER2
FILTER2
FILTER2
```

How can I fix this, and is there a way to implement a lazy filter through a lazy reduce?

**Acknowledgements**: This exercise and the implementation of the above functions were inspired by the book *Functional Programming in Scala* by Chiusano and Bjarnason.

Comment: `filter` is not lazy because `reduce` is not lazy. I don't think you can implement a lazy `filter` with a non-lazy `reduce`.

Comment: @Sweeper is there a way to make reduce lazy?

Comment: What about not using reduce at all?

Comment: @Sweeper I had a go at that. See the post for updates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the version that you wrote without `reduce`, the case where the element exists but does not satisfy the predicate is not lazy. Instead of wrapping the recursive call in a supplier lambda as you did in the other case, you eagerly get the tail and immediately filter it.

```
public Stream<T> filter2(Predicate<T> p) {
    System.out.println("FILTER2");
    T elem = head.get();
    if (elem == null) {
        return generate(() -> null);
    } else {
        if (p.test(elem)) {
            return new Stream<>(
                () -> elem,
                () -> this.tail.get().filter2(p)
            );
        } else {
            return this.tail.get().filter2(p); // <- not lazy!
        }
    }
}
```

What you need is a way to create a stream such that the decision as to whether it's empty or not is deferred until later.

```
public class Stream<T> {
    // private constructor(s)

    public static <T> Stream<T> empty() { /* ... */ }

    public static <T> Stream<T> cons(Supplier<T> head, Supplier<Stream<T> tail) { /* ... */ }

    public static <T> Stream<T> lazy(Supplier<Stream<T>> stream) { /* ... */ }

    public Stream<T> filter(Predicate<T> p) {
        if ( /* this stream is empty */ ) {
            return Stream.empty();
        } else if ( /* head element satisfies predicate */ ) {
            // lazily filter tail, cons head element
        } else {
            return Stream.lazy(() -> this.tail.get().filter(p));
        }
    }
}
```

Something along those lines.

Comment: I see. How would you make it lazy?

Comment: Go back to the drawing board, figure out a different design that lets you create a stream in such a way that you defer the decision as to whether it's empty.

Comment: The Scala code that I read was much easier to understand (using Lisp-like `Cons`). Sure, I'll go and try out a different design!

Comment: I would suggest providing three basic ways of creating a stream (whether constructors or static factory methods): one that takes no arguments and returns the empty stream, one that takes the head and tail and returns a non-empty stream, and another that takes a `Supplier<Stream<T>>` and returns a possibly empty stream, deferring that decision until later for the sake of laziness.

Comment: I understand the purpose of the first two factory methods, but what is the third factory method used for? I'm confused by this statement: "another that takes a `Supplier<Stream<T>>` and returns a possibly empty stream."